# fprintf does not display value properly

Tags: c

I'm trying to represent a battle cards game :

```
typedef struct list_of_cards* p_loc;
typedef struct game game_s;

struct list_of_cards {
    char card[4]; // card is represented like 10C or KS
    p_loc ncards; // next card
};

struct game {
    p_loc loc; // list of card
    p_loc lcard; // last card
}; 

p_loc init_cards(p_loc loc, int n) {
    loc = malloc(sizeof(struct list_of_cards));
    scanf("%s", loc->card);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", loc->card);
    if (n == 1)
        return loc;
    init_cards(loc->ncards, n-1);
}

int main()
{
    int n; // the number of cards for player 1
    scanf("%d", &n);
    game_s player1;// the n cards of player 1
    player1.lcard = init_cards(player1.loc, n);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s %s\n", player1.loc->card, player1.lcard->card);
}
```

The first `fprintf` give me what I want (like AD KC QC) but the second displays

> �(�� QC

.
So my question is, why �(�� is player1.loc->card value.
Thanks

Comment: Did not your compiler warn about `init_cards()` not returning a value with `... init_cards(loc->ncards, n-1); }`?  Save time.  Insure all warning enabled. or get a new compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why player1.loc->card is some weird string is due to the fact it is uninitialized and the memory contains random characters which are not always printable in `ascii`.
You need to modify your `loc` in your init to do so you can pass your `loc` as a pointer to the first element of your list,but the best way is probably to initialize you whole player struct in one function.

```
p_loc init_cards(p_loc* loc, int n) {
    *loc = malloc(sizeof(struct list_of_cards));
    scanf("%s", (*loc)->card);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", (*loc)->card);
    if (n == 1)
        {
            (*loc)->ncards = NULL;
            return *loc;
        }
    return init_cards(&((*loc)->ncards), n-1);
}

int main()
{
    int n; // the number of cards for player 1
    scanf("%d", &n);
    game_s player1;// the n cards of player 1
    player1.lcard = init_cards(&player1.loc, n);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s %s\n", player1.loc->card, player1.lcard->card);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to return the allocate card and assign it back to the member `p_loc` of its predecessor.Further you need an output parameter for the last card of the deck:

```
p_loc init_cards( int n, p_loc *lastCard )
                            // ^ output parameter
{
    if ( n <= 0 )                        // terminate recursion
        return NULL;                     // successor of last card is NULL

    p_loc loc = malloc(sizeof(struct list_of_cards)); // allocate new card
    if ( loc != NULL )
    {
        scanf("%s", loc->card);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", loc->card);

        *lastCard = loc;                 // new card is last card
        loc->ncards = init_cards( n-1 ); // next card is successor of act card
    }
    return loc;                          // return new card
}

int main()
{
    int n; // the number of cards for player 1
    scanf("%d", &n);
    game_s player1;// the n cards of player 1
    player1.lcard = NULL;
    player1.loc   = init_cards( n, &player1.lcard );
    fprintf(stderr, "%s %s\n", player1.loc->card, player1.lcard->card);
}
```

But you can easily do that without recursion:

```
p_loc init_cards( int n, p_loc *lastCard )
{
    *lastCard = NULL;
    p_loc head;
    p_loc *act = &head; // init pointer to first card
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i ++ )
    {
        *act = malloc( sizeof(struct list_of_cards) ); // allocate next card right to target
        if ( *act == NULL )
            break;

        scanf( "%s", (*act)->card );
        fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", (*act)->card );

        *lastCard = *act;         // last card is act card
        act = &((*act)->ncards);  // set pointer to member ncards of last card
    }
    *act = NULL;                  // successor of last card is NULL
    return head;                  // return first card
}
```

Comment: what about the last card ?